# Can't import product names/descriptions with special characters

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, character-encoding

I'm trying to import a product CSV which has Bulgarian product names/descriptions (using the standard import under import/export->import)

The only way I've been able to import any so far is by wrapping them in quotes or by putting roman characters in front of the Bulgarian.

e.g. 'Ламинирани ПДЧ' or xxx Ламинирани ПДЧ

without adding these characters it outputs the error: Required attribute 'name' has an empty value in rows: 1

It seems like the Bulgarian is being stripped out completely? My file is encoded as UTF-8 and I've also set the default charset as UTF-8 in the htaccess file.

Is it possible to import the Bulgarian without quotes/roman characters? Im hoping it works out of the box but if there's a programmatic solution to it then that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Importing should not be a problem as long as all characters are in UTF-8 and the enclosing characters are present. I assume that you have an error in your input file, e.g. invalid escaping. So please double check your input file. I find it best to use LibreOffice for handling data import files as it a) handles UTF-8 correctly (unlike MS Excel) and you can easily specify delimiters and quotes.

Also check for non-printable characters that might conflict with the import.

Comment: I've installed LibreOffice but i'm still getting the same result. The following text gives me the error that the name attribute field is empty: ламиниран

I'm only able to import when adding roman characters first i.e abc ламиниран . It imports fine then, I've also tried with 2 separate csv files from different sites. Are you able to import ok with the text I just pasted above?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are non-printable characters preceding your string. Have you checked e.g. using Notepad++?

Comment: I'm on a mac and using sublime text, but the content is all comma delimited and looks ok e.g:  `,Use config,Ламинирани ПДЧ,some value,` . Do you know if there's a programmatic solution to this?

Comment: Did you have a look at magmi (http://magmi.org/)? Magmi offers enhanced features for mass product import. There's a chance that it will display possible input errors better than the default import functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Google sheets for this problem, MacOS Excel does not support UTF-8 in CSV so most of the time the Cyrillic words are no go.

So I found out Google drive as very useful tool, specially for Magento import.
It require account but MS Office require license.  90787u8u